# How To show fetch events from api in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

code:

```
"use strict";
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
    drop: function() {
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    },
    eventLimit: true,
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://www.example.com/calender_api", 
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    var obj = doc;
                    $(obj).each(function () {                          
                            events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start')
                        });
                    });                     
                    if (callback) callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
});
```

calender_api.php:

```
[{start:"2019-03-06",title:"Conference"},{start:"2019-03-13",title:"Recruiting And Staffing"}]
```

I have created an event calendar which is looking fine the problem is that How can I show event from `calender_api` as I mention above? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you don't have to use the ajax function. just add the url to your php script to your event sources - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources

Comment: How can I add and fetch data from url @John

Comment: ``$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
      url: '/myfeed.php', // use the `url` property
      color: 'yellow',    // an option!
      textColor: 'black'  // an option!
    }

    // any other sources...

  ]

});``

Comment: @John OP is not using event sources here, they only have one event feed. Not using the "eventSources" option is not the cause of the problem. But I agree that using the URL-only approach would make sense here. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have copied and pasted the code from the fullCalendar documentation example (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) almost line-for-line without trying to understand it. It clearly mentions that the code there is aimed at translating data from an XML response into the JS object format required by fullCalendar. You don't have that problem here, because your PHP is already returning JSON, which can be parsed directly without transformation.

You can either

a) change your ajax code a little so it just returns the data directly to fullCalendar:

```
success: function (doc) {
  callback(doc);
}
```

Or

b) replace the whole thing with just the URL, since it already conform's to the fullCalendar specification shown in this approach: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

```
events: "https://www.example.com/calender_api"
```

When you do this, fullCalendar will take care of launching the AJAX request and processing the response for you.

Comment: I had replaced the whole code with of `events` with `events: "https://www.example.com/calender_api"` but still it shows nothing but when I enter data of `calender_api` manually then it shows event @ADyson

Comment: have you checked your browser console for any errors? Have you checked your browser's network tool to ensure that the call to the calendar_api URL is succeeding, and that its "response" contains the data you expect (just the JSON, without any extra content, e.g. extraneous comments, HTML, hidden characters, or spaces etc)? This is basic debugging you can do yourself and might give you a clue what the problem is. If all you can say is "it doesn't show up" then it indicates you haven't tried to investigate the problem using the tools available to you.

Comment: Anyway I do wonder about your URL. Are you perhaps getting a 404 error if you try to go there? What happens if you paste `https://www.example.com/calender_api` (or the real equivalent) into your browser window directly? Does it return the JSON? Because unless you have got some clever extra routing rules in your PHP or your Apache config, then I'd expect you'd need to put the .php extension on the end, i.e. `https://www.example.com/calender_api.php`. Check what the actual issue is. If you're getting a 404 Not Found error, then try that URL with .php on the end instead.

Comment: Once you've got a valid URL, then based on the code and data you've shown, it should work. Here's a demo of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9x73m5we/ . All I did was replace the URL with a dummy endpoint (provided by http://myjson.com) containing your sample data, and it works without any problem.